# IPTables rules are set to allow web traffic, ufw is disabled but still getting connection refused.

Tags: iptables, firewall, ufw

Here is my iptables rules.

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N f2b-sshd
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A INPUT -d XXX.XX.XX/XX -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d XXX.XX.XX/XX -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A f2b-sshd -s XXX.XX.XX/XX -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -j RETURN
-A f2b-sshd -j RETURN
```

I have also disabled ufw just to test if I can access server through http or not, but still I am getting connection refused error.

Is there anything else I can do to allow traffic for http. ?

Comment: How do we know that it is a problem with iptables ? Where are you connecting from ? You need to accept new connections, and if you are running a public web server, why not simply accept all traffic of ports 80 and if you are usin ghttps 443 ? Is there some reason to make your rules overly complex ? Some reason to reject sports or dports lower then 1024 ? And you already accepted those ports earlier so everything after DROP is irrelevant anyways?

Comment: Your rules are a mess, lol. you are running `-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd` twice and you are filtering traffic by sport and dport at some points, but then accepting all traffic at other points. Also as you are using fail to ban we really need to see all your iptables rules and your fail2ban rules. Hard to debug cryptic rule sets such a drop xxxx and yyy and then ask why some unknown ipaddress is rejected.

Comment: You do not really need fail2ban as iptables will do everything fail2ban does. `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m tcp -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name SSH --rsource

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m recent --update --seconds 600 --hitcount 8 --rttl --name SSH --rsource -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: @bodi.zahen My thoughts exactly.  The following rules should be enough for what is being asked `-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`...`-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT `...`-A INPUT -j DROP` But then again, perhaps the question was too vague to begin with...

Comment: Don't use DROP lol http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~peterb/network/drop-vs-reject

Comment: @user633551 - You need to accept NEW as well as RELATED and ESTABLISHED.

Comment: I thought that was being handled by `-P INPUT ACCEPT` rule.  In any case you could just do `-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT` but would then also need to accept output for established tcp connections on port 80....without the  `-P OUTPUT ACCEPT` rule that is.  As for `DROP vs REJECT`...give me a break will ya? ;)

Comment: thanks for all your suggestions, actually I am bit novice in iptables stuff, restored to default rules and now everything is fine.  Thanks for the help.